# How to change the font size and color of markdown cell in Ipython (py 2.7) notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a paper in Ipython notebook, therefore I want to decorate it a little bit. Usually I do it with the "#" to change the size. However, I noticed that the # stops working when the indent is more than 4

```
###Python Paper
       ####Python Oaoer
```

I also tried:
          
        .text_cell_render {
        font-family: Times New Roman, serif;
         }
        
However it shows invalid syntax error.

Another method I tried was to locate the ipython in my laptop. That went south too. Could anybody elaborate a little.

I am fairly new to Python, forgive my ignorance and request for spoon-feeding. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to change the appearance of your notebook, please refer to this document:
[iPython style sheets](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Carreau/posts/blob/master/Blog1.ipynb)

CSS in a cell is not recommended but is possible like so:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>

div.cell { /* Tunes the space between cells */
margin-top:1em;
margin-bottom:1em;
}

div.text_cell_render h1 { /* Main titles bigger, centered */
font-size: 2.2em;
line-height:1.4em;
text-align:center;
}

div.text_cell_render h2 { /*  Parts names nearer from text */
margin-bottom: -0.4em;
}


div.text_cell_render { /* Customize text cells */
font-family: 'Times New Roman';
font-size:1.5em;
line-height:1.4em;
padding-left:3em;
padding-right:3em;
}
</style>
""")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot. This is very detailed and helpful, gracias